# Reset select to default value with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a following question for AngularJS. I have a 
select with options created with ngOptions. I want to 
set selected option back to default option. I tried to 
delete model variable e.g:

```
if(angular.isDefined($scope.first)){
    delete $scope.first;
}
```

But this not working. Here is my html.

```
    <div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
            <select data-ng-model="first"  data-ng-options="item.name for item in selectContent" required="required">
              <option value="" style="display: none;">-- select --</option>
            </select>
            {{first.value}}
<hr/>
        <input type="button" value="reset dropdown" data-ng-click="resetDropDown()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectContent = [
        {
            name: "first",
            value: "1"
        },
        {
            name: "second",
            value: "2"
        }
    ];

    $scope.resetDropDown = function() {
        if(angular.isDefined($scope.first)){
            delete $scope.first;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zono/rzJ2w/

How I can solve this problem?

Best regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your reset-button is placed outside of the div containing your controller. This means that your reset-function does not exist in the context where you try to use it.

Change to:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <select data-ng-model="first"  data-ng-options="item.name for item in selectContent" required="required">
          <option value="" style="display: none;">-- select --</option>
        </select>
        {{first.value}}
        <hr/>
        <input type="button" value="reset dropdown" data-ng-click="resetDropDown()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's always a good idea to use a debugger to make sure the code you're trying to fix is actually being executed.

Comment: My error. This is just example code. Not actual code in me project. I have edited code +1.

Comment: @GeorgiNaumov Well, it works with that change: http://jsfiddle.net/rzJ2w/7/ As far as I can tell the select-dropdown is reset to its original value. Was that not what you wanted?

Comment: So .. Both solution working but in me code this don't work. Usually I use your way - with delete. Will dig into me code. Problem is not with delete.

Comment: You should be able to just set it to `null` rather than deleting the attribute.

Answer (score 6):

```
$scope.resetDropDown = function() {
    $scope.first = "";
}
```

Comment: I like how simple this answer is. In my case I choose from a price dropdown and then click 'update all' after this is updated I want it to reset so I can just set it to "" which is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Solution above works for Windows and Android, but did not work for iOS browsers. Probably events are happening in different order there.

So for my code I:

1. created ID for select element, so I could easily find it by
   iQuery;
2. created delayed invocation of to statements to ensure the
   reset is happenning at the very end;
3. and just in case was
   resetting in two ways (but just first way was actually enough in iOS
   too);

```js
  function resetDropDown () {
   $timeout(function(){ 
       $scope.first  = '';
       
       // jQuery way
       $('select#idOfSelectElement option:first' ).prop( 'selected', true );
   }, 200);
  }
```

Comment: Never mix AngularJS with jQuery code! Eventually, it will mess up data bindings and event handling, if you introduce a second framework.