# Angular : Reset dropdown based on another input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface

I am using a dropdown in a table, which by default shows list of options topped by a blank option. When I select any valid option from the list, this blank option disappears.

My requirement: Whenever a condition specified for another column is satisfied, then the dropdown should come back to its original position. That is that blank option has to be included again, as displayed by default in the first stage.

Is there anyway to reset the dropdown with blank option, just like it got displayed so, when the div is loaded for the first time ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is too broad, you'll need to post some code of what you have done.

Comment: just modify your scope variable to blank

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991168/reset-select-to-default-value-with-angularjs...... as the accepted answer suggests call that code when ever your condition is true

Comment: Thanks for responses.

Comment: My question here is whether we can refresh the dropdown element after selecting an option, to bring back its original state ( that is with blank option coming by default) ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,this is my solution.
Whenever a condition specified for another column is satisfied set a scope variable as true,say `$scope.condition=true` and in your select tag add an option like this

```
<select ng-model="selectedName">
<option ng-selected="condition"> </option>
<option  ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for responses. My question here is whether we can refresh the dropdown element after selecting an option, to bring back its original state ( that is with blank option coming by default) ?

Comment: instead of null you can place whatever u want

Answer (score 0):

Described problem occurs when no default option is set, then `ng-options` sets additional blank space which disappear after first use of select. Solution is to set default option from options array.

Check my code snipped with wrong solution ( Your current one I think ) and correct solution with default value.

```js
var app=angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controller", function($scope){
  
  // notice that no chosenItemFirstSelect is here so
  // we have blank value becaouse no default choose
  $scope.items=[
    {id:1, label:"Option 1"},
    {id:2, label:"Option 2"},
    {id:3, label:"Option 3"}
  ];
  
  //correct way of doing this
  
  $scope.itemsCorrect=[
    {id:0, label:""},//default option is in options array
    {id:1, label:"Option 1"},
    {id:2, label:"Option 2"},
    {id:3, label:"Option 3"}
  ];
  
  //MOST IMPORTANT IS TO CHOOSE OPTION 
  //choose default value
  $scope.chosenItemSecondSelect=$scope.itemsCorrect[0];
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <div>
    <h3> Wrong solution </h3>
    <label>Select without default value and without blank option</label>
    <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="chosenItemFirstSelect"></select>
  </div>  
  <hr>
  <div>
    <h3> Correct solution </h3>
    <label>Correct Select with ng-model and with blank option:</label>
    <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in itemsCorrect track by item.id" ng-model="chosenItemSecondSelect" ></select>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responses. My question here is whether we can refresh the dropdown element after selecting an option, to bring back its original state ( that is with blank option coming by default) ?

Comment: But this blank not controlled option is wrong approach. If You want to go back to default option use the second solution and set ng-model value to default option.